# What happens if I used this internal fan with broken blade?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling

This is the fan of HP 15-da1xxx laptop with broken blade, what happens if I continue using it? P.S:The fan was already making cracking noise and car engine sound before the breakage of the blade, it didn't broke on its own, it broke during dusting it. I am looking for a temporary solution to use the laptop for few hours/days until getting the new replacement fan which is currently unavailable.
Would an external cooling pad assist the cooling of the CPU and prevent the broken blade from causing any damage?

[image: The image of the Fan]

Comment: At the very least, the fan bearings will wear out quicker.

Comment: The unbalance will wear the bearings more than normal, so the fan might stop working at all, so that your system might overheat, it can lead to vibrations which might damage other components, ...

Comment: I wouldn't bother with external cooling pad, I'd just get a new fan due to the noise - it's supposed to be pretty quiet. Replacement part nr you'll find in the [Maintenance Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06691790.pdf). HP original part might be pricey, but you can probably find compatible for 10 - 20 dollars.

Comment: @DanielB - "At the very least, the fan bearings will wear out quicker" - "The fan was already making cracking noise and car engine sound before the breakage of the blade." - **That likely already happened.**

Comment: The blade didn't break from its own actually, it broke will cleaning it. And thank you all for your answers

Comment: Where is the missing fin? Did you remove it, or is it still in the fan housing? If it's still in there, it could easily find a way to break more fins off, or stop the fan from spinning altogether.

Comment: Breaking the blade that is exactly opposite to the missing one would improve the balance at the cost of cooling performance. In this case *the* blade that is exactly opposite does not exist, the fan had 37 blades. Still, getting rid of one of the almost-exactly-opposite blades should improve the balance. I'm not sure if I would attempt to do this if I were you though. Replacing the part is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

When your fan is broken, you might fry your CPU, resulting in a broken computer, or in worse case a fire in your home.

Replace it.

Comment: Wouldn't an external cooling pad assist the cooling of the UCP and prevent the broken blade from causing any damage?

Comment: @Coder: do you want to take that risk?

Comment: @Coder - "Wouldn't an external cooling pad assist the cooling of the UCP and prevent the broken blade from causing any damage?" - No; An external cooling pad will not prevent the CPU from overheating. **The fan is broken, you need to replace it, instead of trying to find ways to contiue using a broken fan**

Comment: Thank you, I am just looking for a temporary solution for few hours/days until I get the replacement fan which is currently unavailable

Comment: Repeated use *can* cause damage eventually.  However, there is NO risk of a fire.  The CPU will thermal throttle itself or turn off.

Comment: @Keltari: I have worked as a serverroom maintenance engineer, and one day the white wall was not so white anymore :-)

Comment: @Dominique Are you ***specifically*** saying a a ***CPU*** overheated and was the cause of the fire?

Comment: @Keltari: No. That particular fire was caused by something else. However, I have burned my fingers opening up servers with a badly working fans, hence I always advise serious caution in such cases.

Comment: @Dominique Then why are you answering the OP's question by saying it can start a fire, when it wont?

Comment: Because it MIGHT start a fire. Security above all!

Comment: @Dominique Absolutely not.  CPUs will thermal throttle themselves or just shut off if they overheat.  Nor do they pull enough power to cause a fire, even if they built in protection failed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said in a comment, you only plan on using the computer for a few hours or day, you will be fine.  Replace the fan assembly as soon as possible.  The noise is from the fan no longer being balanced.  The longer you run the fan, the faster it will wear out though.